# Apache Solr 4 - after 1st commit the index does not grow

Tags: solr, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I have written my own plugin for Apache Nutch 2.2.1 to crawl images, videos and podcasts from selected sites (I have 180 urls in my seed). I put this metadata to a hBase store and now I want to save it to the index (Solr). I have a lot of metadatas to save (webpages + images + videos + podcast).

I am using Nutch script bin/crawl for the whole process (inject, generate, fetch, parse... and finally solrindex and dedup) but I have one problem. When I run this script for a first time, there are stored approximately 6000 documents (Lets say it is 3700 docs for images, 1700 for wegpages and the rest of docs are for videos and podcasts) to the index. It is ok...

but...

When I run the script for a second time, third time and so on... the index does not increase the number of documents (there are still 6000 documents) but a count of rows stored in hBase table grows (there is 97383 rows now)...

Do you now where is the problem please? I am fighting with this problem really long time and I dont know... If it could be helpful, this is my configuration of solrconfix.xml http://pastebin.com/uxMW2nuq and this is my nutch-site.xml http://pastebin.com/4bj1wdmT

When I look into the log, there is:

```
SEVERE: auto commit error...:java.lang.IllegalStateException: this writer hit an OutOfMemoryError; cannot commit 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2668) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2834) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:2814) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:529) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.run(CommitTracker.java:216) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a lower value before autocommitting? Try to commit for every 100 documents to avoid having too much information in memory.

Comment: Thank you additionaly. That was the problem.

Comment: I've added the comment as the answer, so you can accept it. Thanks for following up this late. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with a lower value before autocommitting? Try to commit for every 100 documents to avoid having too much information in memory.